# Get time from remote server for ios app

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdate

I would like to know how my iOS app can get the datetime from a distant server (NTP ? Other..?), and not with local iPad datetime ; and transform it on NSDate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp seems to be a NTP framework for iOS which gives you

```
[NSDate networkDate];
```