# Need Date From Remote API

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am working on an App where i Get Date. I don't want to use System date. I searched stack overlflow and found this link

[Get time from remote server for ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851161/get-time-from-remote-server-for-ios-app)

But the solution given in the link states "**This is a work in progress"**

Is there any simple Framework for iOS to get a Date from other frameworks

Comment: get it from webservice... what's a big deal?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you need actually server link? maybe this will help. http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

Comment: since i dont have web service as of now. i am trying some third party API's  @ Fahim Parker

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko The link which you have provided is what i was searching for.. A simple date API

Comment: post as answer so that can mark as right answer

Comment: @XCodian : wait, how can Alex answer is right answer? that is webservice... it WON'T tell your server date or time... RIGHT?

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko : http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json gives me 11:59 AM... though its 14:59 here in kuwait

Comment: It's UTC timezone(+0000). If you want local time, you need to convert it according your local timezone.

Comment: i am not going to use it.. i am just using this for temporary purpose @FahimParkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying you have remote server, means you must be having the webservice in your app.

If you have webservice, get the time using webservice.

Comment: since i dont have web service as of now. i am trying some third party API's

Comment: if you don't have webservice, how remote server is coming in picture?

Comment: the web service for my project will be provided later yaar... i am trying by fetching date from other APIs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this api](http://timezonedb.com/api). You can get time by providing latitude and longitude.